# magento 1.9 custom mail

Tags: php, magento

try to make a custom form and send mail when user submit that form but page not work always get 404 error when try to submit page

i am follow this tutorial to make page

https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/

i am using magento version 1.9

copy code in following path

i am using custom magento theme dukan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to design yuor phtml file, find this :

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/inchoo/
```

find this:

```
<form id="simple_contact_form" name="simple_contact_form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('inchoo-simplecontact/') ?>index/sendemail" method="post">
```

and change it to -

```
<form id="simple_contact_form" name="simple_contact_form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('inchoo-simplecontact/index/sendemail') ?>index/sendemail" method="post">
```

if it was helpful, tap +1 and answer :)

Comment: index.php/inchoo-simplecontact/index/sendemail/index/sendemail

Comment: can you copy and paste here your request in browser input field??  something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295364 ?  Copy after get 404 error pls.

Comment: can you tell me how use more than one $mail->setBodyText in this code i have to sent more than one variable

Answer (score 0):

what kind of error do you have? where do you going? mage.test/mail/index  or another adress?? push yours zip archive of project. I will check and say to you

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0a8f03ced7e287c52c1ec2c4d3c0f10d20181114092040/9e2481

Comment: index.php/inchoo-simplecontact/index/sendemail  in url and page not found error

Comment: /app/etc/modules/Inchoo_SimpleContact.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_SimpleContact>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Inchoo_SimpleContact>
    </modules>    
</config>